# Is there a way to connect to AKS node, which has a private IP without opening the routes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am looking for a way to connect to AKS node, which has a private IP. The challenge is we cannot get the routes open. Are there some workarounds?

Comment: Nope, without the routes the network not able to send your traffic to the destination. Can you try with Azure Portal Terminal?

Comment: This problem is not specific to Azure Kubernetes, private IP in internal network are not accessible outside to other application.

Comment: What do you mean cannot get he routes open?

Comment: Does it work for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/aks/ssh